# html within json broken json

Tags: php, json

The result of my json is invalid.

Json

```
{
    "item": {
        "title": "Japanese investors back Lookup, a messaging app for local shopping in India",
        "desc": "An infusion of US$116,000 from Japan's social games company DeNA and Teruhide Sato, founder of BEENOS, takes the three-month-old startup\u2019s seed funding to US$382,000.",
        "link": "https:\/\/www.techinasia.com\/dena-teruhide-sato-beenos-fund-lookup\/",
        "content": "<p><img src="https: \/\/www-techinasia.netdna-ssl.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/01\/lookup-app-main-720x289.jpg" alt="lookupappmain" width="720" height="289" class="aligncentersize-largewp-image-213938" \/><\/p>\n<p>Bangalore-based instant messaging app <a href="https: \/\/www.techinasia.com\/tag\/lookup\/">Lookup<\/a> – a Craiglist cum WhatsApp for local businesses – just got its third dose of seed funding. Japan&#8217;s leading social games company <a href="https: \/\/www.techinasia.com\/tag\/dena\/">DeNA<\/a> and Teruhide Sato, founder of BEENOS group, a global conglomerate with ecommerce holdings and a business incubator, invested US$116,000 into this three-month-old startup founded by Deepak Ravindran, a young serial entrepreneur.<\/p>\n<p>“Both our recent investors have strong footholds in the mobile space and have successfully led innovations in Japan,” says Ravindran, suggesting that the investors would be giving Lookup more than just funding.<\/p>\n<p><a href="http: \/\/www.lookup.to">Lookup<\/a> lists businesses, restaurants, and even police stations for users to connect with. Unlike Craigslist or JustDial which would give you a number to dial, Lookup lets you shoot off a message to the local businesses without leaving the app. You can find prices and availability of products or services at local businesses, book appointments at salons, or make reservations at restaurants with this app. Any store or restaurant using Lookup can then respond instantly.<\/p>\n<p>Lookup has a call center tracking the messages to ensure that its users receive responses immediately, even if a store is not using the app. “Our guarantee is that you get answers within five minutes. We do this by employing dedicated people for handling your request. Lookup’s call center fields your responses, calls up stores, and types answers back to you in real-time. No calling, no waiting,” Ravindran told <em>Tech in Asia<\/em>.<\/p>\n<p>To celebrate the latest funding from Japanese investors, Lookup is gifting free sushi for a week to new users from Bangalore who download the app. For this, it has tied up with two Japanese restaurants Shiro and Ginseng.<\/p>\n<p>With this latest infusion, Lookup’s seed round of venture capital funding closed at US$382,000. It had earlier bagged US$166,000 from tech billionaire Kris Gopalakrishnan, co-founder of Indian IT bellwether Infosys, and US$100,000 from MKS Switzerland SA, a precious metals and financial services group of companies.<\/p>\n<p><center><strong>See: <a href="https: \/\/www.techinasia.com\/college-dropout-turned-mit-top-innovator-rolls-craigslist-whatsapp-app-local-shopping-india\/">College dropout turned MIT top innovator rolls Craigslist and WhatsApp into one app for local shopping in India<\/a><\/strong><\/center><\/p>\n<p>This post <a href="https: \/\/www.techinasia.com\/dena-teruhide-sato-beenos-fund-lookup\/" title="JapaneseinvestorsbackLookup,
        amessagingappforlocalshoppinginIndia">Japanese investors back Lookup, a messaging app for local shopping in India<\/a> appeared first on Tech in Asia.<\/p>"
    }
}
```

My PHP

```
$arr = array();
$arr["item"]["content"] = htmlentities($content); // $content is dynamic, not fixed template. 
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Anything to solve this?

Comment: what do you want exactly? your question is unclear !

Comment: I second that. This question should be put on hold until it has been made more clear.

Comment: @MustafaMJalal how to produce valid json

Comment: Okay I think I know what she's trying to do. You need to escape the input text properly. I was under the impression that json_encode did that though.

Comment: no wait.. i get it.
try [$content]

Comment: @MustafaMJalal what does that mean?

Comment: u need to make a nested array...

Comment: forget about [$content]
can you wrap your json with []

Comment: @MustafaMJalal can you post an answer? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php
`json_encode($arr,true)`
`json_decode($arr,true)`
try this

Comment: This option parameter is available in PHP 5.3 and above

Comment: @NirajBurde my php is version 5

Comment: @jamieeason So this option parameter (true) won't support in your case. Try adding slashes to the HTML content before encoding it into json format. Double quotes in HTML content is the reason of invalid json output.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping double-quotes using `addcslashes`

```
 $content = htmlentities($content);
 $arr["item"]["content"] = addcslashes($content,'"');
 echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this:

```
addslashes(htmlentities($content));
```

Or:

```
addcslashes(htmlentities($content), '"\\/');
```